# Copying tags in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, copy, clipboard

I want to copy HTML to the clipboard.  This example should copy the button inside `tagHolder`, but it copies `<span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13.3333px; text-align: center; background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);">button</span>`.  Instead (in Chrome), I need it to copy the `innerHTML` of `tagHolder` i.e. `<button>button</button>`.

```js
function $id(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function doCopy() {
    var tagHolder = $id('tagHolder');
    tagHolder.style.visibility = '';
    copy(tagHolder)
    tagHolder.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function showCode() {
    var code = $id("xxx").innerHTML;
    $id("txtinfo").innerText = code;
}

function copy(element) {
    if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(element);
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
    }
    document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="doCopy()">copy</button><br />

    paste:<br />
    <div id="xxx" contenteditable="true" onpaste="setTimeout(showCode, 1);" style="border: 1px solid black;"></div>
    html:<br />
    <div id="txtinfo" style="border: 1px solid black;"></textarea>

    <div id="tagHolder" style="visibility: hidden;"><button>button</button></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [clipboardjs](https://clipboardjs.com/) as demo'ed in [davidwalsh's blog](https://davidwalsh.name/clipboard)

```
function $id(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function doCopy() {
  var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.tagHolder');
}

function showCode() {
  var code = $id("xxx").innerHTML;
  $id("txtinfo").innerText = code;
}
```

```js
function $id(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function doCopy() {
  var clipboard = new ClipboardJS('.tagHolder');
}

function showCode() {
  var code = $id("xxx").innerHTML;
  $id("txtinfo").innerText = code;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.0/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="doCopy()">copy</button><br /> paste:

<br />
<div id="xxx" contenteditable="true" onpaste="setTimeout(showCode, 1);" style="border: 1px solid black;"></div>
html:<br />
<div id="txtinfo" style="border: 1px solid black;"></div>

<div class="tagHolder" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#xxx" style="visibility: hidden;"><button>button</button></div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet does not work, but I've managed to test it and It still copies a `span...` instead of `button`